# Creating a subgraph using a bipartite network

Tags: r, rstudio, igraph, bipartite, subgraph

I have a dataset of movies and actors - each line is a combination of the two. I want to create a graph in which movies are connected when they share two or more actors. The list of the actors are saved in the actors.2000 variable.

I have already performed such an analysis taking the actors as vertices. Now I want to do this the other way around. However, if I change the data from actors to movies and take the proj1 of the bipartite.projection command, the induced.subgraph returns an empty graph.

```
library(igraph)
all.actors <- dt.movie.actor[, list(name=unique(actor), type=TRUE)]
all.movies <- dt.movie.actor[, list(name=unique(movie), type=FALSE)]

all.vertices <- rbind(all.actors, all.movies)
g.movie.actor <- graph.data.frame(dt.movie.actor[, list(movie, actor)],
                                 directed=FALSE,
                                 vertices=all.vertices)


g.actors <- bipartite.projection(g.movie.actor)$proj2


g.actors <- induced.subgraph(g.actors, vids = V(g.actors)$name %in% actors.2000)
```

My code for the graph with the movies as vertices, looks as follows. I first look up the movies in which the actors participated. Then I use the bipartite projection command to build a network of only the movies. Than I use the induce.subgraph command to filter only the movies that are in the movies.actors.2000 vector.

```
actors.2000 <- dt.awards.actor[award == "72nd_Annual_Academy_Awards__The_2000", 
                              actor]
movies.actors.2000 <- dt.movie.actor[actor %in% actors.2000, list(unique(movie))]
movies.actors.2000

g.movies <- bipartite.projection(g.movie.actor)$proj1
g.movies <- induced.subgraph(g.movies, vids = V(g.movies)$name %in% movies.actors.2000)

summary(g.movies)
```

However, when I use the summary command, it returns an empty graph. I have no clue what I am doing wrong.

Anyone who could help me?

Comment: Could you please update your question to include a sample of your data that reproduces the problem?